# Mysql Pivot rows to columns

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have a table of data which some of data looks like below.

```
Table name Uk_Small_Stage1

name                                             created    1m  
IA UK Smaller Companies                          17/10/2017 3.9
Jupiter UK Smaller Companies I Acc               17/10/2017 6.96
Old Mutual UK Smaller Companies Focus R Inc GBP  17/10/2017 2.19
TB Amati UK Smaller Companies B Acc              17/10/2017 4.85
TM Cavendish AIM B                               17/10/2017 2.34
```

I want to pivot the table to look like

```
Created  IA UK Smaller Companies  Jupiter UK Smaller Companies I Acc  Old Mutual UK Smaller Companies Focus R Inc GBP
17/10/2017      3.9                         6.96                        2.19
```

(a column should appear for each row against the field "name".

The Uk_Small_Stage1 has multiple records for each date.

I am trying to use the code below which should dynamically build and execute the pivot but am getting mysql errors.

Could any one help please?

```
SET group_concat_max_len=2048; 
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(name = ''',
      name,
      ''', 1m, NULL)) AS ‘,
CONCAT("`”,name,"`")
)
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM UK_Small_Stage1;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT created, ', @sql, ' FROM UK_Small_Stage1 GROUP BY created’);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Latest code

```
SET group_concat_max_len=2048; 
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(name = ''',
      name,
      ''', 1m, NULL)) AS ‘,
CONCAT(''',name,''')
)
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM UK_Small_Stage1;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT created, ', @sql, ' FROM UK_Small_Stage1 GROUP BY created’);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Getting MySQL errors - which ones?

Comment: I see a problem here `("\`”,name,"\`")` for example with wrong character just before a comma.

Comment: #42000You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT created, ', @sql, ' FROM UK_Small_Stage1 GROUP BY created’);
PREPARE s' at line 6

Comment: Code to generate pivot code... http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot